# How to handle Push Notifications that App received When App is not running

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I tried to handle all notifications App received while App is not running.

Push notifications are handled in Foreground and Background.

In NOT RUNNING STATE, if notifications received, Then banner is shown.
If tap that banner, App is opened, And I handle that notification with LaunchOption.

But then how can I handle all notifications that aren't tapped?

I tried to solve this problems with `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:)`. But I think that this method is executed in multi thread, So sometimes it is not progressed sequentially.

I'd like to find the better way to solve this problem.

I'm making messenger App. And push notification is the way to receive messages. So, I should handle all notifications I received while app is not running to show user the messages

Comment: You used the correct approach with `getDeliveredNotifications`, and you are right that it is asynchronous - it’s mentioned in the docs. Why doesn’t this work? Why do you need to process all notifications?

Comment: I'm making messenger App. And push notification is the way to receive messages. So, I should handle all notifications I received while app is not running to show user the messages

Comment: How do you want solve notifications that aren't tapped? I don't understand...  Check out how messenger or whatsapp behaves... What do you wxactly want to do when notification arrives and is not clicked? Have you checked Silent push notification?

Comment: I want to save the contents of notifications that received in Not Running state and not tapped. So I'd like to handle them each time they arrive or handle them all at once when App start to run.

Comment: Delivery of push notifications is not guaranteed. The first thing your app should do on launch is check with your backend for any new messages.